# queue by copy or by reference

Tags: c, freertos

There are two ways in which queue behavior could have been implemented:

1. Queue by copy
   Queuing by copy means the data sent to the queue is copied byte for byte into the
   queue.
2. Queue by reference
   Queuing by reference means the queue only holds pointers to the data sent to the
   queue, not the data itself.

I want to ask if queuing by copy a structure that contain a pointer will create a copy or a direct access to the memory pointed.
thank you.

Comment: Is it your own implementation or queues from some library?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'queuing by copy a structure that contain a pointer will create a copy or a direct access to the memory pointed'

Comment: it is queues in the freertos api

Comment: If it is a generic queue implementation, I would guess it's "copy" feature only works one level deep.

Comment: i mean if you have 2 tasks and use xQueueSend() in the first one and xQueueReceive() in the second one and then try to dereference the pointer in the second task and change the data will this affect data in first task??

Comment: Which part of the queueing mechanism might be able to allocate memory and copy data from the inner pointer if your data type cannot be known?

Comment: If it modifies the object pointed to then yes, because it points to the same memory in both tasks (assuming the tasks share the same address space).

Comment: Agreed with @IanAbbott, and copy is safer to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: i am confused because i have read something saying there is a dirty trick in C that does allow you to pass an array by value in C

Comment: typedef struct
{
  int my_array[10];
} Array_by_val;

void func (Array_by_val x);

Comment: how can i pass an array by copy??

Comment: you can't, if you want to access it from a different task, use a poolmem (but be extra careful to free the poolmem pointer).

Comment: yes i want to send array to an other  task and i want The sending task can immediately re-use the array that was sent to the
queue.without waiting the receiving task they must be indepandant how shall i proceed?does the array must be copied?

Comment: Opens an other question and details a lot !

Comment: @Mohamed well then, either copy the data into a wide queue or, mallocate/depool the buffer initially, queue its pointer and immediately mallocate/depool a new one, so reseating the pointer.  Which is best?  Who knows.  If ten bytes, copy it in. If 10,000 bytes, use pointers.

Comment: These kind of things are always tradeoffs.  malloc/depool takes time/cycles durng which an O(something probably less than n) lock is kept on the memory/pool manager.  Copying into a wide queue takes O(n) time/cycles during which a lock is kept on the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for your question is that it depend.

assuming the next struct:

```
struct a_t
{
  int id;
  char *name;
};
```

when assigning one instance of the struct to another the source is copied, but it is a shallow copy.

In general when the inner pointer point to dynamicly allocated block, and the only pointer to the allocation is in the struct, I would say it require a deep copy, if you just assign the memory may leak...

#### in some cases shallow copy is enough:

```
//assume you have a dictionary, or other container to save all names:
char dictionary[][] = {"name1","name2","name3"};
a_t a1 {1, dictionary[0]};
a_t a2=a1; //shallow copy is enough
```

The memory won't leak if you copy one instance to other since all the pointers are saved in the dictionary.

in other cases it doesn't, so you should perform a deep copy, mainly when the struct member is freed in one instance and you don't want it affect the other instance.

#### like in the following:

```
void fill(a_t **ppa, int id, const char* name)
{ 
  a_t *pa = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
  pa->id = id;
  pa->name = strdup(name);
  erase(*ppa);
  *ppa = pa;
} 
void erase(a_t *pa)
{
  if(pa){
    free(pa->name);
    free(pa);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes - that's the other good point - some things just cannot be copied, or it is very expensive/risky to do so.